# Input string error EOF

Tags: python, input

I am making a program to demo different types of graphs using matplotlib, and I am having an issue with user input.

My program has been working since I created it, but when I ran it today upon start up I am getting an error and I just cannot figure out why.

Here is the code that is throwing the error

```
if options == 0:
            fileX = input("Enter the file of x coordinates > ")
            fileY = input("Enter the file of y coordinates > ")
            title = input("Enter title for the graph > ")   
            xlabel = input("Enter a name for the x-axis > ")
            ylabel = input("Enter a name for the y-axis > ")
            g.linegraph(title, xlabel, ylabel, fileX, fileY)
```

here is the error (my files' names are 10int1, and 10int2)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sam/Documents/GraphDemo/src/GraphDemo.py", line 25, in <module>
    fileX = input("Enter the file of x coordinates > ")
  File "<string>", line 1
    10int1
         ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

can someone help to explain why this error is being thrown? It has worked up until now. I've tried different files, and different ways to input but I get the same error every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running Python 2.7?

If so, `input` attempts to evaluate the input as a Python expression. When you enter `10int1` as the input, it attempts to evaluate this as a string, which it isn't – there are no opening/closing quotes.

Instead, you should use `raw_input`, which simply returns a string (without attempting to evaluate). Then, you should convert that input to an integer or whatever type you require.

Comment: This worked, but then I got another error because I removed `self` from `def linegraph(self, title, xlabel, ylabel, fileX, fileY):` then it stopped working again when I readded `self` to fix the error

Comment: Nevermind the above comment. I just cleaned the code and it worked